# How to call git show head:<fileName> in jgit?

Tags: git, jgit

I want to use "git show head:" in jgit. But I haven't found the relevant API, can someone tell me how to execute it

Comment: I want to get the file content and version number on git from git's url.                          
But I don't want to use jgit to pull a repository locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit)** is An implementation of the Git version control system in pure Java.

Since you could not call a `git show head:<fileName>` in Git for a *remote* repo, similarly you cannot do so with JGit.

Any such call would use a remote server API, like GitHub [`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) : that would allow to see the content of a file *without* having to clone a Git repo.
And that would use a regular `curl`, no JGit required.

Comment: Thank you,I think there's something wrong with my thinking。My requirement was to write a plugin in Jenkins that required me to get information about a specific GIT file.Before, my colleagues used powershell to get GIT information, but now I write plug-ins in Java.I think I should use jpowershell to implement it. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @lhx Agreed: if this involves communication with a remote referential, JGit won't help (unless for the default remote operations: clone, pull, push, ls-remote).